# DocuSign API embedded signature implementation Symfony

Tags: php, docusignapi, symfony-2.8

Trying to implement the DocuSign embedded signature into our web application and I have a hard time getting it right. The documentation is a bit scattered so I'm not able to get the correct flow of API calls. Though I set up the quickstart project from Docusign but that didn't help in getting me right.

Here's the scenario: We want the user's(might be multiple) to be able to sign documents from our website. The document has the following fields to be filled along with the signature field: `Date`, `Name`, `additional comments`, and `number`. The document would be provided from within the app. Now I need to know the correct sequence of steps to be followed to achieve this scenario via PHP SDK.

I've created the App and Integration keys via Developer account.

**Update**

I've been able to put together this code:

```
$accessToken = $this->generate_jwt_token();
        $config = new Configuration();
        $config->setHost('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi');
        $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $accessToken);
        $api_client = new ApiClient($config);
        $api_client->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath('https://account-d.docusign.com');
        $api_client->getConfig()->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        $api_client->getConfig()->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $accessToken);


        // Create an envelope from a template
        $relativePath = "/../web/dummy.pdf";
        $basePath = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . $relativePath;
        $signer_name = 'John Smith';
        $signer_email = 'jhon@yopmail.com';
        $envelope_summary = $this->create_envelope_from_pdf($basePath, $signer_name, $signer_email, 'Dummy PDF', $api_client);

// Generate the URL for the embedded signing ceremony
        $envelope_id = $envelope_summary->getEnvelopeId();
        $recipient_name = 'John Smith';
        $recipient_email = 'jhon@yopmail.com';
        $signing_ceremony_url = $this->generate_signing_ceremony_url($envelope_id, $recipient_name, $recipient_email, $api_client);

// Redirect the user to the signing ceremony URL
        header('Location: ' . $signing_ceremony_url);
        exit;


function generate_jwt_token() {
        $private_key_path = 'PRIVATE_KEY';
        $jwt = array(
            'iss' => 'ACCOUNT_ID',
            'sub' => 'USER_ID',
            'aud' => 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi',
            'exp' => time() + 3600
        );
        $jwt = JWT::encode($jwt, $private_key_path, 'RS256');
        return $jwt;
    }

    /**
     * @throws ApiException
     */
    function create_envelope_from_pdf($pdf_path, $signer_name, $signer_email, $document_name, $apiClient)
    {
        // Set up the envelope definition
        $envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        $envelope_definition->setEmailSubject('Please sign this document');
        $envelope_definition->setStatus('sent');

        // Add the document to the envelope
        $document = new Document();
        $document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents($pdf_path)));
        $document->setName($document_name);
        $document->setFileExtension('pdf');
        $envelope_definition->setDocuments([$document]);

        // Add the signer to the envelope
        $signer = new Signer();
        $signer->setName($signer_name);
        $signer->setEmail($signer_email);
        $signer->setRecipientId('1');
        $signer->setClientUserId('1234');

        // Add a sign here tab to the signer
        $sign_here = new SignHere();
        $sign_here->setDocumentId('1');
        $sign_here->setPageNumber('1');
        $sign_here->setRecipientId('1');
        $sign_here->setTabLabel('Sign Here');
        $sign_here->setXPosition('100');
        $sign_here->setYPosition('100');
        $signer->setTabs(new Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here]]));
        $envelope_definition->setRecipients(new Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]));

        // Create the envelope
        $envelopes_api = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
        $envelope_summary = $envelopes_api->createEnvelope('ACCOUNT_ID', $envelope_definition, new CreateEnvelopeOptions(['cdse_mode' => 'true']));

        return $envelope_summary;
    }

    /**
     * @throws ApiException
     */
    function generate_signing_ceremony_url($envelope_id, $recipient_name, $recipient_email, $apiClient) {
        global $api_client;
        $recipient_view_request = new RecipientViewRequest();
        $recipient_view_request->setReturnUrl('https://example.com/');
        $recipient_view_request->setClientUserId('1234');
        $recipient_view_request->setAuthenticationMethod('none');
        $recipient_view_request->setUserName($recipient_name);
        $recipient_view_request->setEmail($recipient_email);
        $recipient_view_request->setRecipientId('1');
//        $recipient_view_request->set('https://www.example.com');
        $envelopes_api = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
        $recipient_view = $envelopes_api->createRecipientView('ACCOUNT_ID', $envelope_id, $recipient_view_request);
        return $recipient_view->getUrl();
```

and now I'm getting this error:

```
Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [401] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:9:"errorCode";s:27:"AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN";s:7:"message";s:59:"The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed.";}
```

The JWT token is generated correctly. The error occurs when call to `EnvelopesApi ->createEnvelope` happens.

Comment: You want us to write the code for you? or do you have an issue? like an error? or some other thing that's not working or unclear?

Comment: Thanks, @InbarGazit. Pls check the edit. I've been able to put a basic implementation together.

Comment: can you try to use $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken() to get the access token instead of doing it yourself? the SDK provides this method so that you don't have to figure out how to do JWT

Comment: Getting this error now : 
`Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"error";s:13:"invalid_grant";s:17:"error_description";s:16:"issuer_not_found";}`

Comment: Are you using the values that were set by quickstart?

Comment: No. I created a separate app for this.

Comment: Something is wrong with the configuration, integration key, the way it's setup, the RSA key etc. Need to make sure it's all configured correctly. It's easier to use quickstart as it just does this all for you

Comment: @InbarGazit I tried the quickstart values as well but it's giving the same `invalid_grant` error. Can you check if this code works for you?

Comment: It does, what project did you select from quickstart? JWT? Auth Code Grant?

Comment: @InbarGazit, I selected the option which had both JWT and Auth code grant.

Comment: ok, and you use the values that were created in the configuration file inside the ZIP file in your code?

Comment: Most importantly is the private RSA key, it has to match exactly what you got

Comment: Yep all values are the same. It's a bit strange

Comment: Does it work directly from the quickstart code?

Comment: Yes quickstart code works

Comment: OK, that's good. Can you perhaps only extract the JWT code from quickstart and into your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve the problem of generating an access token via `requestJWTUserToken` DocgSign PHP SDK method by specifying the `OAuthBasePath` explicitly via the below code:

```
$api_client->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath('account-d.docusign.com');
```

In the absence of this code, it was set to production OAuthBasePath i.e. `account.docusign.com`.

Updated Code for JWT token generation method:

```
function generate_jwt_token(ApiClient $apiClient) {

        $relativePath = "/../web/private.key";
        $basePath = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . $relativePath;
        $jwt = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken('Integration_Key', 'USER_ID', file_get_contents($basePath), ['signature', 'impersonation']);
        return $jwt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adrian from DocuSign Developer Support here,

Your code looks good, however, your JWT section has some incorrect values:

This:

```
 $private_key_path = 'PRIVATE_KEY';
        $jwt = array(
            'iss' => 'ACCOUNT_ID',
            'sub' => 'USER_ID',
            'aud' => 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi',
            'exp' => time() + 3600
```

The iss should be your integration Key, not the Account iD,

The aud should be "account-d.docusign.com".

And don't forget to add the scopes:
"scope": "signature impersonation"

Here is our PHP JWT Guide with a good code sample, just in case:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdks/php/auth/

This is how we code it:

```
 self::$apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath($GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['authorization_server']);
    true);
    $privateKey = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['private_key_file'], true);

    $scope = DocuSign::getDefaultScopes()[0];
    $jwt_scope = $scope . " impersonation"; 

    $response = self::$apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
       $aud = $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_client_id'],
       $aud = $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_impersonated_user_id'],
       $aud = $privateKey,
       $aud = $jwt_scope
    );
```

We hope this information helps.

Regards
Adrian
DocuSign Developer Support

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Event with the correct values, the manual way of generating access token is giving a malformed value resulting in the error: `"errorCode";s:27:"AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN";s:7:"message";s:59:"The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."` When I use the `requestJWTUserToken` of the PHP SDK, it generates this error: `Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"error";s:13:"invalid_grant";s:17:"error_description";s:16:"issuer_not_found";}`